# How can I use an image inside a 'ListView' as link to another 'view' (page) using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am having difficulty going to the next page when I am touching the image on the interface? I trying to set a category Listview. The listview holds the image and how can I set it when the user touches the image, so they can go to the next page?

The code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'custom_textW.dart';

class Category {
  final String name;
  final String image;

  Category({@required this.name, @required this.image});
}
List<Category> categoriesList = [
  Category(name: "Sarapan", image: "nasilemak.png"),
  Category(name: "Kuih", image: "kuih.png"),
  Category(name: "Makan Tengahari", image: "lunch.png"),
  Category(name: "Minum Petang", image: "mnmptg.png"),
  Category(name: "Makan Malam", image: "mknmlm.png"),
  Category(name: "Minum Malam", image: "mnmmlm.png"),
  Category(name: "Minuman", image: "air2.png"),
];
class Categories extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 109,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categoriesList.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.red[200], offset: Offset(4, 6), blurRadius: 20)
                  ]),
                  //tambah di sini kalau nk gesture
                  child: Image.asset(
                        "images/${categoriesList[index].image}",
                        width: 80,
                      ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                CustomText(
                  text: categoriesList[index].name,
                  size: 14,
                  colors: Colors.black,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how the listview looks like:

[image]

right now when I am trying to touch the image, nothing will happen. It just displays the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the image widget inside the InkWell Widget and implement onTap() method to navigate to next page.

```
child: InkWell(
   onTap: ()=> NavigateToPage(),
   child: Image.asset(
          "images/${categoriesList[index].image},
          width: 80,
   ),
),
```

Comment: how can I determine when I am tapping the  Sarapan image, it will go to sarapan page, and when I am tapping the Kuih image, it will go to kuih page? . The image should be able to go to different pages which will hold different type of content..

From what I understand on the code, it told any image will go to the one same page.

Comment: You need to write logic according to that, inside onTap only.

Comment: child: InkWell(
                    onTap: ()=> Navigator.of(context).push(
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new SarapanPagi(),)
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                          "images/${categoriesList[index].image}",
                          width: 80,
                        ),
                  ),
.......... i am sorry I am not clear on that particular subject. i did the improvement and it did work to go to the next page.

Comment: You can also use onTap(){ // write your logic here }, if you want to use multiple line logic.

Comment: onTap: (){
                      if(categoriesList[index].image == "nasilemak.png"){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new SarapanPagi()));
                        }
                    },

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your image with `GestureDetector` like this:

```
child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: // go to next page,
    child: Image.asset(
        "images/${categoriesList[index].image}",
        width: 80,
    ),
),
```

Comment: how can I determine when I am tapping the  Sarapan image, it will go to sarapan page, and when I am tapping the Kuih image, it will go to kuih page? since what I understand on the code, it told any image will go to the one same page.

Comment: You can set your routes to be the value of category image value.  Then use Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(categories[index].image,)